# String and add special characters from a list in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

In Haskell I used to use filter to strip set of numbers from a list. However, I have not been able to make it working with this particular case.

I have a list of strings as follow:

```
["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]
```

I want to string the `[]` and `""` so the final string is (with spaces):

```
A B C D E F A B N
```

shouldn't a simple filter like `print filter([) ["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]` remove the `[`?

**update:**

I read over [this document](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) and was able to get the following result:

```
let example = (concat (intersperse " " ["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]))
print example
-- this prints "A B C D E F A B N"
```

However, when I use this :

```
-- where createalphs create a list of strings
-- and userinput is a string entered by the user 

let setofalph = ($ createalphs $ words userinput)
let example = (concat (intersperse " " setofalph))
print example
```

I get this error

```
Couldn't match expected type `[[Char]]'
In the second argument of `intersperse', namely `setofalph'
In the first argument of `concat', namely
  `(intersperse " " setofalph)'
In the expression: (concat (intersperse " " setofalph))
```

Comment: Is `["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]` your string, i.e. `"["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]"`, or is it a list of strings? You're quite unclear.

Comment: @gspr sorry it is a list of strings

Comment: Right, so then it makes no sense to "strip the []"! That's just notation for the list. Do you, instead, want to turn a list of strings into a string with all the elements comma-separated?

Comment: your `setofalph` takes a function call it like this `let example = setofalph unwords`, you probably wanted `let setofalph = createalphs $ words userinput` instead of `let setofalph = ($ createalphs $ words userinput)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unwords` works fine:

```
λ> unwords ["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]
"A B C D E F A B N"
```

Additionally, `Data.List.intersperse` would help, along with `concat`.

```
import Data.List

solution :: [String] -> String
solution =  concat . intersperse " "
```

What this does is separate each value in the list with `" "`, then join (concatenate) the lists together.

If you want to separate with `", "`, you can easily change the above function:

```
solution :: [String] -> String
solution =  concat . intersperse ", "
```

so that:

```
λ> solution ["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]
"A, B, C, D, E, F, A, B, N"
λ> putStrLn $ solution ["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]
A, B, C, D, E, F, A, B, N
```

To put this into the context of your IO:

```
main = do
  x <- getLine
  putStrLn $ solution $ createalphs $ words x
```

Comment: the problem is that I am getting a string from the user and will pass it to a function. So for example `print  $ createalphs $ words userinput` will print `["A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","N"]`. Now I want to remove the `""[]`.

Comment: @RainMan I've done exactly that. Just to make it clearer, I added the IO function at the end.

Comment: great, thank you. One quick question, is it possible to have it like `let example = ($solution $ createalphs $ words x) putStrLn = "String is" ++ example ` ? when doing so I get an error

Comment: Why the first `$`? Do you know what that function does? If not, I recommend that you look at some introductory material (sorry, no link, on phone).

Comment: Just a note: `concat . intersperse x` == `intercalate x`.